# Values not passed into Component from application-dev.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, profile

I am writing tests in Junit and am using Spring Boot Framework (which I am new to) and need to use different urls to test different environments
Hence, I created 2 resource files in addition to application.properties

```
1> application-dev.properties
2> application-stage.properties
```

I created a component which I set the property values to be read into.

Lastly in my test file I am annotating the Test Class with:
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ComponentName.class})`

Also in my application.properties I have this line:
`spring.profiles.active=dev`

Expected:
When I print out the value of the property of the Component class it should take the value from application-dev.properties

Actual: the value is null, although my bean is successfully created

Why is the property not getting injected with the value from application-dev.properties?

1. I've tried several articles from Baeldung (A bit confusing though, the articles demonstrate multiple methods to do the same thing, but does not show 1 full technique to do everything end-to-end
   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles
2. I also tried with setting the active profile multiple ways:

   a. Env variable
   b. Using `@ActiveProfiles` annotation

Note: This is a Test Project (I am trying to automate-test a website, so all my resource files are inside src.test.resources

application.properties

```
    #spring
    https://ops.dev.website.us
    spring.profiles.active=dev
    url.sms=https://ops.default.website.us
```

application-dev.properties

```
    url.sms=https://ops.dev.website.us
```

application-stage.properties

```
    url.sms=https://ops.stage.website.us
```

Component File

```
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "url")
    public class DevEnvironment {

    private String sms;

    public String getSms() {
    return sms;
    }

    public void setSms(String sms) {
    this.sms = sms;
    }
    }
```

Test File

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DevEnvironment.class})
public class MyTest implements ApplicationContextAware {
  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

  private DevEnvironment devEnvironment;
  String url;
  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Active profiles:" + env.getActiveProfiles()[0]);
    devEnvironment = context.getBean(DevEnvironment.class);
    //System.out.println("from set app context:" + devEnvironment.getSms());
    url = devEnvironment.getSms();

  }

  @Test
  public void testSms(){
    System.out.println("inside test url:" +url);
  }
}
```

Expected: When I print out the value of the property of the Component class it should take the value from application-dev.properties

Actual: the value is null, although my bean is successfully created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `@SpringBootTest` annotation to MyTest class.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest //add
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DevEnvironment.class})
public class MyTest implements ApplicationContextAware {
 //
}
```

I worked fine with this.

reference: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

Comment: wow, that was it! I had that annotation on for debugging when I was trying stuff, but I took it off eventually before reaching this point thinking that it is going to mess up with junit